# Google Fusion Table - Geocode... grayed out

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables, google-earth

I am following a **tutorial on Lynda.com**.  **I have imported exercise data from an Excel Spreadsheet into a Google Spreadsheet** and now I'm trying to create a fusion table.

The spreadsheet contains only two columns (Gas Station Name and Address).

[image]

According to the tutorial, all addresses should be highlighted yellow, because they need to be Geocoded.

[image]

But when I follow the exact steps and go to File / Geocode... that option is grayed out.

[image]

I've noticed that the tutorial is a little dated and Google Drive has changed a bit but for the most part the functionality is still there.  So, how to Geocode now with the latest version?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: What does the data you imported look like?

Comment: Does the "Address" column have the type "Location"?

Comment: As I stated in my question, **"I am following a tutorial on Lynda.com"**, and **"I  have imported exercise data from an Excel Spreadsheet into a Google Spreadsheet."**  I cannot find any way to see if the "Address" column is of type "Location".  **All instructions seem to be old as well.**  https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2590990?hl=en

Comment: You wrote: "I am following a tutorial on Lynda.com". The tutorials on Lynda.com require a login, so we have no idea what that means.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: With your **"hint"** I was able to find the solution.  I'm posting an update to the question to help others who may encounter the same problem.  I suggest you follow up with an answer, so I can give you the points.  **They go go waste on me.**

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "hint" I got from [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) I deleted everything and started from the beginning, looking for any posibility to change the "Address" column have the **type** "Location" and I found it.  Here are the steps to follow for enabling Geocode from the very beginning:

**Step 1)**  Create a new **Google** Spreadsheet:

[image: New Google Sheet]

**Step 2)**  Import the **Excel** Spreadsheet.

[image: File Import]

**Step 3)**  Upload the Excel Spreadsheet (if you haven't already).

[image: Upload File]

**Step 4)**  Select Replace Spreadsheet to import.

[image: Replace Spreadsheet]

**Step 5)**  Click the Import button.

[image: Click Import]

> **Now you have a new Google Spreadsheet with imported data.**

[image: Imported Spreadsheet]

> **Step 6)**  **Create a new Google Fusion Table.**

[image]

**Step 7)**  Select **Google Spreadsheets** to import the data from the newly created Google Spreadsheet.

[image]

**Step 8)** Select the spreadsheet.

[image]

**Step 9)** Click **Select** button and **WAIT!!!!**

[image]

**Step 10)**  When the table appears, click the **Next** button.

[image: Import Table]

**Step 11)**  Accept the defaults and select Finish.

[image]

Now, you have a new Google Fusion Table.

> **------------------------------------------------ IMPORTANT ---------------------------------------------------**
>
> **This is where you change a column to enable Geocoding!!**

**Step 12)**  With the Google Fusion Table opened, click on **Edit** and select **Change columns**.

[image: Change Column Type]

**Step 13)**  From the popup window, **select the column** to geocode and **change its type** to Location.

[image: Found It]

**Step 14)**  Select **Save** and the Fusion Table will now display with the address column highlighted in yellow indicating they need to be Geocoded.

[image]

**Step 15)**  Select **File** and **Geocode...**

[image]

**Step 16)**  Select the **Location column** to geocode and click the **Begin geocoding** button.

[image]

The geocoding is in progress.

[image]

When complete, click the browser refresh and the yellow will be gone.  This means that the column has been geocoded and can now be mapped.

**Step 17)**  If map tab is not there already, click on the **+ tab** and select **Add map**.

[image]

And the map will display:

[image]